# Wrong environment Settings invoked in Commands

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, batch, environment-variables

Getting wrong and extra pathnames in error messages using "For /D", "dir" and "if exist" commands when running the non-Powershell batch code to elevate UAC privileges code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044985/how-can-i-auto-elevate-my-batch-file-so-that-it-requests-from-uac-admin-rights). This has been noted at the end of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238986/iterate-directories-with-batch/27270633#27270633) with voluminous error spam on non existent directories.

[Here](http://1drv.ms/1I5KloU) is a screenshot of such. The problem is the erroneous insertion of "Local" and repeated "Application Data".
These error messages do not appear when *not* using the UAC elevation code.

Is it possible that something in Wscript is invoking the wrong environment settings for HOMEPATH on the WshEnvironment object?

It probably relates more to the upgrade (years ago) of XP to Win 7 HP, where for some reason, the ghosts of "Documents and Settings" "Local Settings" and "Application Data" won't go away.
Simply putting in commands like

```
set LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local
set APPDATA=C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming
```

doesn't change anything. With admin privileges %LocalAppData% doesn't seem right in batch.

Or can we go the registry way with something like:

```
reg.exe add “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders” /v “Local Appdata” /t REG_SZ /d/f
```

Reading up on this a bit it appears the somehow my [junction points](http://www.svrops.com/svrops/articles/jpoints.htm) got broke.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use command prompt. Open the control panel and click system, click advanced link on left hand side, then click the environment variables button on the advanced tab and change your system variables in the bottom window or add new ones there and reboot to be sure they take affect.  The upper window is for user environment which mean that changes there are only effective for the logged on user, so I recommend making your changes in the bottom(system variable) window for batch coding.  If I am misunderstanding your post then let me know here.  Your question is a bit confusing as worded but I think I got it right. You can also right-click on the computer(or my computer icon in XP) and click properties to get to the same advanced settings.  Just check the tabs until you find "Environment Variables" button at bottom of tab. Acutally though you can use setx but is easier to use the GUI if you are not a big user of the cmd prompt. Can also try out kixstart for batch coding to set variables etc.  is a powerful batch code option.

Comment: My bad: the question is amended a little. All the environment variables seem ok in the CP. I think we might have to venture a little further under the hood.